# lightning-tab not receiving focus when page is loaded

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-tabset, accessibilty

We have a page on experience cloud. We have two tabs and used `lightning-tab` inside `lightning-tabset` for this.

We have tried to provide the focus by using focus event as follows -

```
this.template.querySelector('lightning-tab').focus();
```

Also, we have tried giving the value to `active-tab-value` attribute.

But the tab is not receiving focus at all.

Please refer to the following code for reference.

searchPortal.html
[image]
searchPortal.js
[image]

Can someone help with this?

Comment: Could you please add some code for reference? Without the code , the question is too broad.

Comment: @Rohit I have provided the code for reference.

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. Can you add screenshot of what UI is visible to you ?